# How to access values from MSQL database in a drop down menu in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a website using PHP and MYSQL.
and i made a form to add categories for the blog and stored it in the table of categories.
Now i want to access those categories in the drop down menu in another form of blog . Can anyone solve my problem?

Here is the code of form:

```
 <html>

  <head>
     <title>Create a Blog!</title>
  </head>

 <body>
 <?php
    include_once ('BlogClass.php');
    $j = new Blog();
    $ans = array();
    $ans = $j->DisplayCategories();
 ?>

   <form name="BlogTopic" action="BlogTopicProcess.php" method="post" onSubmit="return validateForm()">
  topic_cat :
      <select name="topic_cat">
         <?php
             for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $ans ); $i++ ) {
         ?>
         <option value="<?php echo($ans[$i]['Category']);?>"><?php echo($ans[$i]   ['Category']);?></option>
         <? php 
             }
         ?>
      </select>
      <label><strong>topic_id:</strong></label>
      <input name="topic_id" type="text"/><br>         
      <label><strong>topic_subject:</strong></label>
      <input name="topic_subject" type="text"/><br>

      <label><strong>topic_date:</strong></label>
      <input name="topic_date" type="text"/><br>

      <label><strong>topic_by:</strong></label>
      <input name="topic_by" type="text"/><br>

      <input type="checkbox" name="terms" />
      I agree to the <a href="#">terms &amp; conditions</a>  <br>                    
      <input type="submit" value="Create Topic" /><br>
 </form>     

 </body>
</html>
```

The function `DisplayCategory()`

```
public function DisplayCategory() { 
    $connection=$this->Con->connectDb(); 
    $data=array(); 
    $sql="select * from categories"; 
    $query=mysql_query($sql); 
    $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query); 
    if ($numrows!=0) { 
        while ($a=mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
            $data[]=$a; 
    } 
    mysql_close($connection); 
    return $data; 
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? What's in the variable $ans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know what values your $ans contains, but this might help you

```
<select name='topic_cat'>
   <?php foreach ( $ans as $a ) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $a['key']?>"> <?php echo $a['value']; ?> </option>
   <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Lets avoid using comments like Thanks you and +1 as they just add noise to site, if you find any answer suitable just vote it up. :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstable you must delete the blank here

```
<option value="<?php echo($ans[$i]['Category']);?>"><?php echo($ans[$i]   ['Category']);?></option>
```

to

```
<option value="<?php echo($ans[$i]['Category']);?>"><?php echo($ans[$i]['Category']);?></option>
```

if doesnt work then must check the method `DisplayCategories()` what type returns and in witch format. 
Send us the code of this method

replace the code `$data[]=$a;` with this `array_push($data,$a);`

Comment: public function DisplayCategory()
  {
    $connection=$this->Con->connectDb();
    $data=array();

    $sql="select * from categories";

    $query=mysql_query($sql);
    $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
    if ($numrows!=0)
    {
      while ($a=mysql_fetch_array($query))
      $data[]=$a;
    }
    mysql_close($connection);
    return $data;
  }

Comment: The columns Category is real column in your table categories? If the column name is category then you must put category with lowercase latter. if it is ok replace the code  $data[]=$a; with this array_push($data,$a); Try this

Comment: -1: It doesn't make any difference if the blank is there or not, that's just cosmetics. Replacing `$data[]=$a` with `array_push($data, $a)` doesn't make any difference either.